# Binding data from a promise to a react component is inaccessible

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have two classes, one being a child component called article.  I want to pass data to the article component after receiving data in the parent, which is my app.js.  However, I am unable to drill down into the data from the response that I am setting in the App constructor--the data I am trying to access is undefined, but I am able to print the full response out fine, including the data that I am unable to drill down into.  I would like to tie the articles array from the following JSON to my respective article components. 
Data is being pulled from: https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?sources=google-news&apiKey=edd0276dc8344c2abaeb40a3f6fb439f

```
class Article extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.props.title = props.title;
    this.props.description = props.description;
    this.props.url = props.url;
}

render() {
  let pic = {
  uri: 'https://cdn.vox-cdn.com/thumbor/M8Nb8mKymSEN59T2iDIe5XXiNTw=/0x146:2040x1214/fit-in/1200x630/cdn.vox-cdn.com/uploads/chorus_asset/file/11738447/VRG_ILLO_2761_Spacecraft_Sidebyside.jpg'
};

return (
  <View style={styles.article}>
        <Header/>
        <Text>Two rockets launched within 15 minutes of each other Wednesday morning</Text>
        <Image source={pic} style={{ height: 250}}/>
        <Text numberOfLines={3}>Early in the morning on July 24th, rocket enthusiasts will have the lucky experience of being able to watch two launches at roughly the same time. Around 7:30AM ET, SpaceX is slated to launch one of its Falcon 9 rockets from the California coast, while Europe…</Text>
    </View>
);
}
}

export default class App extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    let url = 'https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?sources=google-news&apiKey=edd0276dc8344c2abaeb40a3f6fb439f';

    this.state = fetch(url)
    .then(function(response) {
        response.text().then(function(text) {
            console.log(text, "TEXT!!!");
            return text;
        });
    });
}

render() {

return (
<ScrollView>
    <Article/>
</ScrollView>
);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't really be doing your `fetch` in the `constructor`.

Here's a working example to get you started:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

const Article = ({ title, desc, url }) => {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <h1>{title}</h1>
      <p>{desc}</p>
      <img src={url} />
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

let url =
  "https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?sources=google-news&apiKey=edd0276dc8344c2abaeb40a3f6fb439f";

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    articles: []
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch(url)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => {
        this.setState({
          articles: data.articles
        });
      });
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.articles.length === 0) {
      return "Loading..";
    }

    const firstArticle = this.state.articles[0];
    const { title, description, url } = firstArticle;

    return <Article title={title} desc={description} url={url} />;
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Working CodeSandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/3ywxz389v6).

Comment: Perfect.  Thank you.  I started learning reactJS and react native a few days ago.  I greatly appreciate the help!

Comment: Also, are you familiar with how to write the Article in react native?  I don't have access to the react-dom module.

Comment: It would be the same as you have it in your example, just return a `ScrollView` with the `Article` in it.

Answer (score 1):

A couple things wrong about this:

- the return type of a `Promise<T>` is a `Promise<T>` unless you `await`, in which case it's `T`.
- you don't assign to `this.state`, state changes in React are abstracted away via `this.setState`

Following,

`this.state = fetch(url)...`

should be changed to

```
fetch(url)
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(text => this.setState({ text }))
```

pass in `this.state.text` (or rename it) as props to the child

edit: as Colin pointed out in the comments below, assigning to `this.state` is fine *in the constructor* (which you are doing). **However**, fetching data is better suited for post-mount lifecycle methods like `componentDidMount`

Comment: Accessing `this.state` this way is fine because it's in the `constructor()`, I think. Having `fetch()` in the constructor is a bad idea though.

Comment: @Colin ah, missed that part. Yes, assigning to `this.state` in the `constructor` is fine. And yes, data operations should go in `componentDidMount`